# What is the %% operator and ExtendedPropertySet

Tags: t-sql

All, I just found the following code when I was trying to read the stored procedure, `sp_addextendedproperty`:

> EXEC %%ExtendedPropertySet().AddValue(Name = @name, Value = @value,
>   Level0type = @level0type, Level0name = @level0name, Level1type =
>   @level1type, Level1name = @level1name, Level2type = @level2type,
>   Level2name = @level2name)

I have some trouble in understanding it. Please help to review my questions.

1. What is the `%%` operator used for ?
2. What is the `ExtendedPropertySet`? It seems it is not a stored procedure or function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short google search reveals the [solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6fae8710-6b8a-4276-85fc-9b02c02b2e78/-operator?forum=transactsql):
`%%` is used for internal objects. So `%%ExtendedPropertySet()` looks like the constructor of an `ExtendedPropertySet` object that SQL Server implements internally.

Comment: Thanks your kind help, I am trying to understand what is the `ExtendedPropertySet`. But didn't found any useful read about it after searching in the google. Yes, as you said , It looks like a constructor of CLR type.

Comment: @Joe.wang I suppose `ExtendedPropertySet` is an object that SQL server implements internally and that is on purpose not documented and shall not be used by you. What do you want to do with that object? Or are you just curious?

Comment: I just felt curious with it. I searched it in the msdn . didn't found any document about it. It seems microsoft doesn't intend to let the developer to consume it directly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but hope this reply would be helpful to anyone who is still looking for more information like I did.

`ExtendedPropertySet()` is executed in system stored procedure "`sp_addextendedproperty`".

```
EXEC %%ExtendedPropertySet().AddValue(
    Name = @name, 
    Value = @value, 
    Level0type = @level0type, 
    Level0name = @level0name, 
    Level1type = @level1type, 
    Level1name = @level1name, 
    Level2type = @level2type, 
    Level2name = @level2name)
```

It seems like that this method sets extended properties of the given database object.

For instance, following statement will set the Description property of column B_ADD in table CUSTOMER to "Billing Address".

```
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty 
  @NAME = N'MS_Description', @VALUE = N'Billing Address', 
  @LEVEL0TYPE = N'Schema', @LEVEL0NAME = N'dbo', 
  @LEVEL1TYPE = N'Table', @LEVEL1NAME = N'CUSTOMER', 
  @LEVEL2TYPE = N'Column', @LEVEL2NAME = N'B_ADD';
```

Check the following statement:

```
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty 
  @NAME = N'MS_Description', @VALUE = N'Customer information', 
  @LEVEL0TYPE = N'Schema', @LEVEL0NAME = N'dbo', 
  @LEVEL1TYPE = N'Table', @LEVEL1NAME = N'CUSTOMER';
```

This will set the property Description of the table CUSTOMER to "Customer information".

So, `ExtendedPropertySet()` in the `sp_addextendedproperty` stored procedure sets extended properties in the given object.